# How to connect an Android App to a Socket.IO server that's hidden behind an Apache server?

Tags: android, node.js, apache, ssl, socket.io

I have a working website with both an Apache server (which handles all requests) and a secondary Node.js server running on port 3000 that the Apache server redirects any requests for a specific URL (/connect) to via a ProxyPass call in . This all works fine for establishing a Socket.IO connection through a traditional browser via JavaScript, using the command:

```
socket = io.connect("/", {path: "/connect/socket.io"});
```

However, I am so far unable to get an Android App that I'm working on to establish a socket connection.

Depending on what I do, I get 2 different errors.

When I specify the port 3000 like so:

```
options.path = "/connect/socket.io";

mSocket = IO.socket("https://example.com:3000", options);
```

I get a connection timeout exception after 10 seconds or so.

2. When I don't specify a port:

   options.path = "/connect/socket.io";

   mSocket = IO.socket("https://example.com", options);

I get an immediate 400 Bad Request response.

Various debugging steps I've already tried:

1. Version mis-matching of Socket.IO. My server is running via Socket.IO version 4.4.0, and I have the following in my build.gradle file:

   implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:2.0.0') {
   exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
   }

Per this page:https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

it seems like client:2.0.0 should be compatible with server 4.4.0.

2. Android permissions. I added the following permissions to my AndroidManifest.xml file:

3. Specify 'transports' as an option in the Java Android source, i.e. :

   IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
   options.path = "/connect/socket.io";
   options.transports = new String[]{WebSocket.NAME};

   mSocket = IO.socket("https://example.com:443", options);
4. Specify SSL as valid:

   SSLContext mySSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
   mySSLContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);

with:

```
private final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts= new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
}

public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
String authType) throws CertificateException {
}

public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
String authType) throws CertificateException {
}
} };
```

5. Specify an OkHttpClient object:

   HostnameVerifier myHostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
   @Override
   public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
   return true;
   }
   };

   OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().hostnameVerifier(myHostnameVerifier).sslSocketFactory(mySSLContext.getSocketFactory()).build();

   // default settings for all sockets
   IO.setDefaultOkHttpWebSocketFactory(okHttpClient);
   IO.setDefaultOkHttpCallFactory(okHttpClient);

I also have a console.log() statement on my Socket.IO server that logs when a new user connects, which isn't happening, so I know the initial handshake isn't ever succeeding.

I'm also testing on a physical android device (Galaxy Note 10+) that is connected to Android Studio via a USB, which (I believe) bypasses some of the networking issues that testing on an Android Virtual Device can have.

I'm decently experienced with web development and server management, but fairly new to Android. Has anyone here who's used Socket.io from an Android (ideally Java) development background got any advice I could try out?

I'm happy to provide any further info if it would be useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some progress!

I noticed that the successful requests (from web browsers) were all using transport=polling instead of transport=websocket, so I switched the line

options.transports = new String[]{WebSocket.NAME};

to

options.transports = new String[]{Polling.NAME};

And I got a successful connection from the Android app!

I thought the webserver was set up to handle both "websocket" and "polling", but evidently I was incorrect about that.

So this now looks like an issue with the server rather than android development since I'm able to handshake successfully with "polling".

Comment: But with polling, android app disconnects and reconnects automatically in few seconds